# Live data fetch from remote database without hitting URL in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application with live commenting.  The problem is all comments are getting stored in remote database by hitting `url`. I am getting data same with sanding comment but for making it live I am hitting `url` in every seconds.

Due to every second of hitting `url`, there are too large numbers of request making my database hang , is there any solution?

Comment: Scale your backend to support the load you require?

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: Buy a bigger or more servers?  Analyse your code on your server to determine why it is hanging?  If you are continually querying your database looking for updates then adopt push notifications instead of polling. Use persistent web sockets?  There could be any number of solutions; but first you need to understand your problem. Your question is too broad for a simple answer.

Comment: can you please let me know the other solutions??

Comment: Not without a much better description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Asynchronous Calling** can help.! While making calls in swift use asynchronous **blocks** or **completion handlers** to make calls to remote server. This wont crash your app. and There should be some sort of handling in DB as well that it can take innumerous calls n still dont crash.